# how to trigger react component from other component

Tags: reactjs, components, redux, react-redux

I want to trigger react component from other component. What is the best way to do it? I don't want to create new flag on redux store like "shouldShowMenu". I thinking about static method in react but i not expert in react.

```
import Menu from './component/menu'
const clickfeed = () => {Menu.staticClickEvent()}
<Provider>
  <Menu>
  <Feed onClick={clickfeed}/>
</Provider>
```

can i use static method like this and should i use static method change the component state.

Answer (score 1):

You should go ahead and create that `shouldShowMenu` flag in your redux store. Once you have components interacting that way, it's an application state. It seems excessive at first but once you start having a value that is shared across components, this will save you a lot of headaches!

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I should go ahead in this way. Did you know when we should use static method in react component.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `redux` for this. You can use `ref` to do this. Hope it helps!

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
//component 1
  var Hello = React.createClass({
    func: function() {
      console.log('I\'m inside Hello component')
    },
    render: function() {
      return <div > Hello World< /div>;
    }
  });


//component 2
  var Hello2 = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount(){
    //calling the func() of component 1 from component 2 using ref
     this.refs.hello.func()
    },
    render: function() {
      return <Hello ref="hello"/>;
   }
  })


ReactDOM.render( < Hello2 / > ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);

</script>
```