# React: Trigger method in child component from different child component

Tags: reactjs

I've created two components in React, `<Search />` and `<List />` that both are children of `<App />`.

When a button in `<Search />` is clicked, I want to fetch something from an API and display the results in `<List />`. While I got this working by doing the fetch inside `<App />` and passing the response as prop to `<List />`, I would prefer to encapsulate the fetch inside `<List />`.

Unfortunately I am having a hard time finding a way to do this. 'The React way' probably would be to do this via some clever prop passing, but I haven't found a neat way to do this – even a 'shouldFetch' boolean would need to be reset after the fetch which seems cumbersome and would trigger unnecessary renders.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39741908/1144247) uses `refs` for something similar which might work, but actually I am a bit hesitant to try it since `refs` seem to be a bit dirty, according to the React docs, as they "imperatively modify a child outside of the typical dataflow".

How can I instruct my `<List />` component to do something after a button in `<Search />` has been clicked?

If required I can supply code – but hoping this question is simpler than it seems to me.

Comment: Are you using Redux? If so, you can dispatch an action from `<Search />`

Comment: @OmriAharon Unfortunately not, plain React for now.

Comment: Then since the only way components receive information (in the "React way") is state/props, you pretty much covered both options. I'd use your first option that you got to work. By the way - `<Search />` seems like a perfectly fine place to call this API (or at least trigger it), and `<List />` should be perfectly happy with just receiving and displaying data.

Comment: A third option might be to fetch in the `<Search />` component, then call a function in `<App />` with the data you received, which would in turn just pass it to `<List />`, so basically `<Search />` handles the call instead of `<App />`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A natural option would be to create a state boolean variable in `<App />`, triggered when a button is pressed in `<Search />` and then use some logic in `<List />` to fetch data when the boolean state went from `false` to `true`.

For example:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { fetchData: false }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Search onClick={() => this.setState({fetchData: true})} />
        <List shouldFetch={this.state.fetchData} onFetch={() => this.setState({fetchData: false})} />
      </div>
    )
  } 
}
```

Then in your `<List />` component:

```
class List extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if ( !this.props.shouldFetch && nextProps.shouldFetch ) {
      // Fetch data here and set it in state, for example
      // After fetch, don't forget to call onFetch() to reset the boolean
    }
  }

  ... // more code
}
```

Although this will work, it is not bad to use `<App />` as the source of data. This way you can abstract pure components that only handles UI but have no network logic. This is often a good model and helps you to reuse components in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a good time to use a store, which will keep the entire state of your app as a single JS object. Flux, Redux are 2 excellent architectures which complement React. Basically, your components listen for changes in the store, when ever any action ( making an api call / click etc ) is carried out the store gets updated and the ui changes. A large scale react application can get very messy to handle with lots of children.

Also completely agree with the above answer, let the `<List />` component be stateless, and only render based on props. Hence having the functions written in the parent `<App/>` and have the data passed down is a good idea.